# add two values to the same column in python

Tags: python, list, data-analysis

I want to add two value to the same column but I'm not sure if it's possible or not,
i want actually to add only the city to the location column, but th problem is that i have a list called `addresses` and it contains the whole addresses and theyy are all differents (even the length) , i've used this code to add only the city but the problem is that sometimes the city is on the position `len(addresses[i])-4` and sometimes not, so i wanted to add two value, i mean `len(addresses[i])-4 and len(addresses[i])-5` to the location column, but is it possible ?

```
coordinates=[]
for i in range(10):
    coordinates.append(np.array([ [df_new['latitude'][i],df_new['longitude'][i]]]))

addresses = []

for coordinate in coordinates:
    addresses.append(geolocator.reverse(coordinate).address)
    
for i in range(10):
    addresses[i]=addresses[i].split(', ')
    df_new['location'][i]=addresses[i][len(addresses[i])-4]
```

this is an example of how it looks the list "addresses" like:

```
['2', 'ottstraße', 'Fechenheim', 'Ost', 'Frankfurt am Main', 'Hessen', '60386', 'Deutschland']
['7', 'Ring', 'Jungen', 'Ulm', 'Baden-Württemberg', '89066', 'Deutschland']
['Roland', 'Schön', 'Sandesneben', 'Lauenburg', 'Schleswig-Holstein', '25629', 'Deutschland']
['Zeiskliniken', '101', 'waldstraße', 'Yorckgebiet', 'Chemnitz', 'Sachsen', '99130', 'Deutschland']
['8', 'Nieksener Straße', 'Bad Oeynhausen', 'Kreis Minden-Lübbecke', 'Nordrhein-Westfalen', '32678', 'Deutschland']
```

Comment: How do you know whether it's -3 or -4? Do you check for "Kreis"?

Comment: i mean -5 sorry, because if you look at the last row, 'bad Oeynhausen is the name of the city and not Kreis Minden-Lübbecke which is on -4 @mcsoini i just checked that manually ! i couldn't find any other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the cities only:

```
for coordinate in coordinates:
    addresses.append(geolocator.reverse(coordinate).raw['address']['city'])
```

Contrary to [`address`](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html?highlight=raw#geopy.location.Location.address), which provides the full address as a string, [`raw`](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html?highlight=raw#geopy.location.Location.raw) will get you a dictionary containing the available osm data, including the city.

Comment: but 'city' is not defined ! how can i define it?

Comment: i get this error, 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-d4ceba571956> in <module>
      6 
      7 for coordinate in coordinates:
----> 8     addresses.append(geolocator.reverse(coordinate).raw['address']['city'])
      9 

KeyError: 'city'

Comment: Can you provide sample coordinates? Also, what geocoder do you use? Just standard osm?

Comment: from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises")

Comment: Thanks, and some sample coordinates?

Comment: i fixed it , using this code :
for i in range(df_new.shape[0]):
    if('city' in addresses[i]):
               df_new['location'][i]=addresses[i]['city'] 
    elif ('town' in addresses[i]):
        df_new['location'][i]=addresses[i]['town']
    elif ('village' in addresses[i]):
        df_new['location'][i]=addresses[i]['village']
    elif ('county' in addresses[i]):
        df_new['location'][i]=addresses[i]['county']
    elif ('state' in addresses[i]):
        df_new['location'][i]=addresses[i]['state']
    else:
        print(addresses[i]) i edited useragent to 'latlongconvert'